# No val_loss and val_accuracy keys when I've already had validation_data in model.fit()'s argument

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, data-augmentation

Here's the image augmentation code:

```py
batch_size = 16

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255, validation_split=0.2)

# test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

# Use flow from dataframe
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
        dataframe=train,
        directory="train_images",
        x_col="id",
        y_col=["not_ready", "ready"],
        target_size=(300, 300),
        batch_size=batch_size,
        class_mode="raw",
        color_mode="grayscale",
        subset="training")

validation_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
        dataframe=train,
        directory="train_images",
        x_col="id",
        y_col=["not_ready", "ready"],
        target_size=(300, 300),
        batch_size=batch_size,
        class_mode="raw",
        color_mode="grayscale",
        subset="validation")
```

Setup the model:

```py
early_stopping = EarlyStopping(monitor='loss',mode='min',verbose=1,patience=7, restore_best_weights=True)

opt = Adam(learning_rate=0.0002)

model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(train_generator,
        steps_per_epoch=train_generator.n // batch_size,
        epochs=100,
        validation_data=validation_generator,
        validation_steps=validation_generator.n // batch_size,
        callbacks=[early_stopping])
```

And print the history keys:

```py
print(history.history.keys())
```

But the results:

```sh
dict_keys(['loss', 'accuracy'])
```

There's no `val_loss` and `val_accuracy` when I've already had `validation_data`. Why is that and how to make them appear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: Make sure your model is running without your `validation_generator`. Second: Make sure your `validation_generator` really does *have* data by iterating through a few samples. Here is a working example:

```
import tensorflow as tf

flowers = tf.keras.utils.get_file(
    'flower_photos',
    'https://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/example_images/flower_photos.tgz',
    untar=True)

img_gen = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255, validation_split=0.2)
BATCH_SIZE = 32

train_generator = img_gen.flow_from_directory(flowers, class_mode='sparse', batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, target_size=(300, 300), shuffle=True, subset="training", color_mode="grayscale")
validation_generator = img_gen.flow_from_directory(flowers, class_mode='sparse', batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, target_size=(300, 300), shuffle=True, subset="validation", color_mode="grayscale")

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=16, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(300, 300, 1)),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(5)
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

epochs=10
early_stopping = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='loss',mode='min',verbose=1,patience=7, restore_best_weights=True)

history = model.fit(train_generator,
        steps_per_epoch=train_generator.n // BATCH_SIZE,
        epochs=1,
        validation_data=validation_generator,
        validation_steps=validation_generator.n // BATCH_SIZE,
        callbacks=[early_stopping])
print(history.history.keys())
```

```
Found 2939 images belonging to 5 classes.
Found 731 images belonging to 5 classes.
91/91 [==============================] - 44s 462ms/step - loss: 1.8690 - accuracy: 0.2298 - val_loss: 1.6060 - val_accuracy: 0.2443
dict_keys(['loss', 'accuracy', 'val_loss', 'val_accuracy'])
```

Also check the parameter `validation_steps` in `model.fit`, if for example it is 0, you will not see the validation loss and accuracy in `history.history.keys()`. If that is the case, try not setting the parameter at all:

```
history = model.fit(train_generator,
        steps_per_epoch=train_generator.n // BATCH_SIZE,
        epochs=1,
        validation_data=validation_generator,
        callbacks=[early_stopping])
```

See the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Sequential?version=nightly#fit) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but without my `validation_generator` it still works. And my `validation_generator` is pretty sure that has data.

Comment: @TeerapadPipadboonyarat can you iterate it over the first five samples and show the output? Also see updated answer.

Comment: I use this code: `for data_batch, labels_batch in validation_generator:
    print("labels batch: ", labels_batch[:5])
    break`

The output is:
`labels batch shape: [[0 1]
 [0 1]
 [0 1]
 [0 1]
 [0 1]]`
Which is match to my CSV file.

Comment: I also print data batch too but it's too long. So here's the sample:
[[[[0.        ]
   [0.        ]
   [0.        ]
   ...
   [0.        ]
   [0.        ]
   [0.        ]]

  [[0.        ]
   [0.        ]
   [0.        ]

Comment: Yes, I did. When I comment out `validation_generator` I have to comment that out too.

Comment: No, you misunderstood, do not comment out `validation_generator`. Just comment out the parameter `validation_steps=validation_generator.n // BATCH_SIZE,`<-- see the bottom of my answer.

Comment: Sorry, for my misunderstanding.
You're right!!!! It does show now.
Thank you so much. Now I've understood it much better now.